# Azure: create a new API Management service without a service URL

Tags: azure, powershell, azureportal

My intent is to configure an **API** (e.g. an **Azure Function**) into **an API Manegement service** using only **policies**. I don't want to specify a **Service URL**.

This is possible using Portal UI:
[image]

but not using **PowerShell Az** module.

Following code:

```bsh
New-AzApiManagementApi -Context $context -Name $fullName -Protocols @('https') `
                                         -Path $path -ProductIds @($product) `
                                         -ApiVersionSetId $apiMgmtVersion.ApiVersionSetId
```

raises this exception:

```
Error : Unable to create 'news' managed API version 1.
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ServiceUrl'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the 
command again.
At C:\Projects\Intranet.ai\component_tools\Install-ApiMgmt.ps1:105 char:76
+ ... able to create '$fullName' managed API version $version.`n$_" | Error
+                                                                     ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Error
```

Is there a way to define an API without a service URL? Maybe using directly `New-AzResource`?

Thanks to anyone who will help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to define an API without a service URL? Maybe using directly `New-AzResource`?

The `New-AzApiManagementApi` seems not support that, you could use the `New-AzResource` directly, please try the sample below, it works on my side.

```
$PropertiesObject = @{
        "name" = "test22"
        "serviceUrl" =  $null
        "path" = "testaaa"
        "protocols" = @("https")
    }
New-AzResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName <Group-name> -ResourceType Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis -ResourceName "<API-management-servie-name>/test22" -ApiVersion 2018-01-01 -Force
```

[image]

Check in the portal:

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to include the `apiVersionSetId`, please try the one below.

```
$versionSet = Get-AzApiManagementApiVersionSet -Context $context -ApiVersionSetId "d41e7f92-9cf8-48fb-8552-d9ae5d4690d3"
$Id = $versionSet.Id -replace "apiVersionSets","api-version-sets"

$PropertiesObject = @{
        "name" = "test22"
        "serviceUrl" =  $null
        "path" = "testaaa"
        "protocols" = @("https")
        "apiVersionSetId" = $Id
    }
New-AzResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName <Group-name> -ResourceType Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis -ResourceName "<API-management-servie-name>/test22" -ApiVersion 2018-01-01 -Force
```

[image]

Comment: this is great! It's exactly what I wanted to achieve. Your help is **very appreciated**. I want to add that in the meantime I've configured `ServiceUrl` with a fake URL and I using **XML policies** the system ignore the field. But will your help my automation script will be perfect! Thanks again

Comment: is there a specific way to set `apiVersionSetId` inside the property object? I think I'm having problem givin directly the version set id I create before.

Comment: Joy Wang, that's **great**! You're a very kind person. Anyway I'll continue experiment on my own.

Comment: @gsscoder Glad to help you, please check my update.:-)

Comment: Joy Wang, you helped me again! I was able to properly set **appVersionSetId** (and I've also setted **apiVersion**). This is great since can help other people too. I'm wondering why this is not documented in official docs... The value added to your reply is that I can see the _path to create resources_ when specific functions are not sufficient. Have a nice day (or better more than nice)! :)

Comment: Joy Wang, there's another difference using New-AzResource instead of specific APIM function. If a call it with a different apiVersion the new version will be overwriten. This doesn't happens with New-AzApiManagementApi. I've checked the JSON export I can see that '/verN' is added to resource name. But this not solve the problem.

Comment: This is my latest attempt: https://gist.github.com/gsscoder/7bde38b8a2fbbd80add148d1058f2ca9. I see also another problem than when we need to attach operations.